# Google Analytics Campaign tracking in Android App

Tags: android, google-analytics

We have implemented Google Analytics Campaign tracking code for our Android App. Everything looks fine except the users count. 
[Google Analytics Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LB4s.png)

In the image you can see that New Users showing as zero and sessions showing the count. What could be the reason for new users not showing the count?

**Here is my code:**

```
 <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

---

```
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
            .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData).build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your campaigns targeting new users? If not, the new users metric possibly will not increase. Another factor to not see new users in your campaigns might be that there was already tracking code installed in your app and you now added the campaign tracking feature(meaning that these users are recognises as returning by GA). That is because the ga:newUsers is described in GA as:
 *The number of sessions marked as a user's first sessions* 
So if your campaign does not target new users this is to be expected.